# Liouville for rationals

Tags: complex-analysis

I have some problems writing a proof down. It concerns the following:

> Let $\displaystyle f(z) = \frac{z^2+2}{z^2(z-1)(z-2)^2}$.
>
> Find the singular part of it's Laurent expansion $B_k(z)$ around $k\in \{ 0,1,2\}$.
>
> Denote $g(z) = f(z) -B_0(z)-B_1(z)-B_2(z)$. Where is $g(z)$ holomorphic?
>
> Prove $g = 0$ using Liouville (without any calculations)

I have found:

$$B(z) = \frac{-1}{2z^2}-\frac{1}{z}+\frac{3}{z-1}+\frac{3}{2(z-2)^2}+\frac{-2}{z-2}$$

where $g(z)$ has removable singularities at $0, 1, 2$.

Could someone please check the following proof? (Proof writing style)

#### Proof:

Since $g(z)$ has a removable singularity at $z=0$ it can be extended. Also note $\exists M$ such that $\forall z \in \overline B(z_0,r): |g(z)|<M$ ($r>0, z_0\in \{ 0,1,2\}$). (because of Weierstrass extreme-value theorem).

Since the degree of $g(z) = -3$, $|g(z)|$ get's smaller as $z\to \infty$. **(1)**

According to Liouville's theorem every bounded entire function is constant. $\Rightarrow g(z) = $ constant. And since $\lim_{z\to \infty} g(z) = 0$ $g$ must equal to $0$.

#### (1)

I think (1) isn't really formal, how could I write this down?

Comment: Just split: $(z+1)/z^2=z/z^2+1/z^2=1/z+1/z^2$?

Comment: Hmm, that happens when you alter the question. The original function is alot more complicated, and the original questions states: 'without any calculations'. Should I change it towards the original function?

Comment: I think that would be a good idea, yes.

Comment: I've altered the question. Working it all out would yield the desired result, but I should use Liouville. The question actually results in 'why is $g(z)$ bounded?'

Comment: shouldn't you specify the point $\alpha$ around which you define the Laurent expansion?

Comment: @benji woops! fixed!

Comment: but now something doesn't make sense to me. if we substitute $f(z)$ with its Laurent expansion around $z=0$ then $f(z) - B_0(z)$ is an entire function. But then $f(z) - B_0(z) - B_1(z) - B_2(z)$ is not defined in both $z = 1,2$

Comment: I don't think it's an entire function. I think there exists an $R$ for which $f(z)$ is holomorphic in $B(0,R)$. Good point though!